# Magento default store view not working at front end

Tags: php, magento, nginx, magento-1.8

I have a `magento 1.8.0` store, and it has two store views for each language `Arabic` and `English`.

Now for the website admin in Manage Stores, the default store view is `Arabic`, but somehow it is not displaying in `Arabic`, it displays in `English`.

The website is running on `nginx` and `php-fpm 5.5` with `zend opcache`.

Please advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have properly installed Arabic language pack and selected in Admin > System > Configuration > General >  Locale for default config.

Comment: Arabic language is installed correctly. As when we change language to arabic, it is working fine.