# magento Default store view not working in front end

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

This question is the duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572624/magento-default-store-view-not-working-at-front-end). None answer this question so far.

I am running a magento 1.9.1.0. And I have two stores, One is English and other one is Arabic.

> My default store view is English in system --> manage stores. But in
>   the front end, arabic page is loading by default.

Why is it so? Any one can please help me with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the locale in `default configuration scope`

> admin > system > configuration > General > Locale Option > Locale

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My configuration settings are as shown in the image. Only difference is the time zone. hope it won't make any effects. Still Arabic store is loading by default

Comment: check with `website` configuration scope

Comment: Double Checked it. Default store view, Main website, and English Store view, everything is english for locale. Only arabic store view has the difference.

Comment: have you install any third party extension

Comment: I have shopgram magento theme, along with it revolution slider and aw blog extension. Thats all, and of course translate pack for arabic. This is all I have.

Answer (score 0):

Check your language.phtml
If you are using flags instead of dropdown make sure you define the default language.
by using `<?php if ($_lang->getCode() != 'default'): ?>`

refer to complete code below

```
    <?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
    <?php if ($_lang->getCode() != 'default'): ?>
        <?php $selected = $_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId() ?>
        <a class="lang-flag<?php $selected && print ' selected' ?>" href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>" height="16" width="24">
        </a>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```